# Oracle SP won't return any rows when passing a NULL parameter value

Tags: c#, sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am calling oracle SP (remote server) from our C# application.

It's accept some parameter values as "Null", hence I am adding parameter like below in C#,

```
objCmd.Parameters.Add("p_DeviceName", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

or,

```
objCmd.Parameters.Add("p_DeviceName", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = null;
```

I suspect both way I am getting empty result set.

Is there any other way we can pass NULL? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't shown us the query. But I suspect you'll find that something like `WHERE Foo = @Foo` won't find a row is a null value of `Foo` due to the way null comparisons work in SQL... you'll want "IS NULL".

Comment: i don't have also query, we just exposed with SP name :), could you please tell more on "IS NULL"?

Comment: this is Oracle SP, we try to call it from C#

Comment: Well then you should show us what the SP does. As for what "IS NULL" is for - before asking an individual for assistance, you should research a topic yourself. A search for obvious terms gives lots of results...

Comment: Post the stored procedure code. You can't compare against NULL. A comparison against NULL is *always* false, even if the field has a null value. That's just standard SQL. This means that `WHERE someField = NULL` will never return any records. The problem is in the stored procedure, you can't fix this with client code (ie from C#)